# itunesconnect error The support URL specified in your app’s metadata

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to publish a application but they refuse it by telling me this

Guideline 1.5- Safety

The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, https://fr-fr.facebook.com/people/Developpeur-Mobileweb/100016130442871, does not properly navigate to the intended destination.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app’s support URL to ensure it directs users to a webpage with support information.

i tried to put google.com, and my facebook profil but they tell me same think

how can i resolve this problem ?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to set up a proper web page, hosted somewhere with support information.  Your Facebook page can't be seen if you aren't logged in to Facebook and even if you are there isn't any real content there about your app.

Comment: What @Paulw11 said is correct. you need to setup a web page with support infoand that url need to be given as support url.

Comment: What is support info? can i setup a web free page ?

Comment: I will create a page on facebook public with information of the app

Comment: You can try that,  it I don't think a Facebook page is going to be accepted.

Comment: I juste try a page facebook with info of my application, i'm waiting for their response

Comment: @Paulw11 it's strange because i have more than 10 application and every time i put a bad url for support and it s the first that apple decline my application for that reason

Comment: It can depend which reviewer you get or Apple may have given their reviewers new guidelines to check support URLs;

Comment: i just get message from apple they validate my application with page i created on facebook

Comment: @Paulw11 ,thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Creating a page facebook with info of my application, and my mail on it, correct my problem, itunes accept my application